# hash tables and 2d vectors

Tags: c++, vector, hashtable, unordered-set

I want to push a 2d vector into a hash table row by row and later search for a row (vector) in the hash table and want to be able to find it. I want to do something like

```
#include <iostream>
#include <set>
#include <vector>
using namespace std;

int main(){

std::set < vector<int> > myset;

vector< vector<int> > v;

int k = 0;

for ( int i = 0; i < 5; i++ ) {
 v.push_back ( vector<int>() );

for ( int j = 0; j < 5; j++ )
 v[i].push_back ( k++ );
}

for ( int i = 0; i < 5; i++ ) {
  std::copy(v[i].begin(),v[i].end(),std::inserter(myset)); // This is not correct but what is the right way ?

// and also here, I want to search for a particular vector if it exists in the table. for ex. myset.find(v[2].begin(),v[2].end()); i.e if this vector exists in the hash table ?

}

  return 0;
}
```

I'm not sure how to insert and look up a vector in a set. So if nybody could guide me, it will be helpful. Thanks

update:

as i realized `std::set` is not an hash table I decided to use `unordered_map` but how should I go about inserting and finding elements in this:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <tr1/unordered_set>
#include <iterator>
#include <vector>
using namespace std;

typedef std::tr1::unordered_set < vector<int> > myset;

int main(){
myset c1;
vector< vector<int> > v;

int k = 0;

for ( int i = 0; i < 5; i++ ) {
 v.push_back ( vector<int>() );

for ( int j = 0; j < 5; j++ )
 v[i].push_back ( k++ );
}

for ( int i = 0; i < 5; i++ )  
 c1.insert(v[i].begin(),v[i].end()); // what is the right way? I want to insert vector by vector. Can I use back_inserter in some way to do this?

// how to find the vectors back?

  return 0;
}
```

Comment: I edited last line. Even for this code I get errors in the inserter line. how should I go about that ?

Comment: I don't see a hash table. Are you talking about `std::set`?

Comment: An STL vector inside an STL vector inside an STL set. Without context it seems like bad design. If you explain the problem you are trying to solve you will definitely receive better advice.

Comment: A `std::set` is not a hash table.  That would be `std::unordered_map` or `std::unordered_set` in the C++0x draft standard.

Comment: I get it. I assumed std::set to be a hash table. All I want is to insert a vector into each bucket of the hash table and search for that vector later in the code. Just like inserting and finding elements.

Comment: Okay, this is a new question now.. there is no default hashing function for `std::vector<>` you need to create one if you intend on using `std::unordered_set`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For inserting use `std::set::insert`, ala

```
myset.insert(v.begin(), v.end());
```

for find, use `std::set::find` ala

```
std::set < vector<int> >::iterator it = myset.find(v[1]);
```

Working example:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <set>
#include <vector>
using namespace std;

int main()
{
  typedef vector<int> int_v_t;
  typedef set<int_v_t> set_t;

  set_t myset;

  // this creates 5 items 
  typedef vector<int_v_t> vec_t;
  vec_t v(5);

  int k = 0;

  for(vec_t::iterator it(v.begin()), end(v.end()); it != end; ++it)
  {
   for (int j = 0; j < 5; j++)
    it->push_back(k++);
  }

  // this inserts an entry per vector into the set 
  myset.insert(v.begin(), v.end());

  // find a specific vector
  set_t::iterator it = myset.find(v[1]);

  if (it != myset.end()) cout << "found!" << endl; 

  return 0;
}
```

Comment: @Sunil, the find above is correct for the code above? `v[1]` refers to a `vector<int>` which contains 5 items (5 through 9) and the `find` finds the matching vector. I'll put up a complete example.

Comment: oops, I changed some stuff to typedefs and left an errant `;`, here is the working version: http://ideone.com/MqttE

Comment: yes I did, I'm just trying to see why the same thing isn't working with my code.

Answer (score 0):

To use `std::copy` to insert into a set:

```
#include <algorithm>
#include <iterator>
#include <vector>

std::vector<int> v1;
// Fill in v1 here
std::vector<int> v2;
std::copy(v1.begin(), v1.end(), std::back_inserter<std::vector<int> >(v2));
```

You can also use `std::vector`'s assign, insert, or copy constructors to do the same.

You are using a `std::set` in this example.  A set does not have a lookup method.  You simply iterate through the set doing operations on each item.  If you want to look up specific items using a hash/key, you'll want to look at data structures like `std::map`.

Answer (score 0):

```
for ( int i = 0; i < 5; i++ ) {
  std::copy(v[i].begin(),v[i].end(),std::inserter(myset)); // This is not correct but what is the right way ?
}
```

It's not correct because you're trying to copy integers from each vector in your vector of vectors into the set.  Your intent, and the type of your set, indicate you want the 5 vectors to be inserted into your set.  You would then simply do this (no for loop):

```
std::copy(v.begin(), v.end(), std::inserter(myset));
```

Comment: So if I want to skip elements, what will I do. like say I want to do i+=2 ?

Comment: Use a for loop instead of std::copy.